# Ignore part of the key in JSON call using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm currently populating some elements with json. However if a new json is loaded. the json looks slightly different. How can I ignore the first part of the key so that it works. I was thinking I could use an asterisk but that gives me a error in firebug.

Here is my jQuery

```
var items = [];
    $.each(data[0].attributes['*.dyn.prop.current.profile'], function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });
    displaySortLabel(items, "type-details");
```

Example JSON 1

```
[
   {
    "avatarDefinitionId":1,
    "avatarName":"edge",
    "attributes":{
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.act.halt":"1",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.current.profile":"1",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.firmware":"1.0",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.ip.address.3g":"192.168.1.1",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.ip.address.cloud.com":"192.168.1.1",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.ip.address.lan":"10.0.0.1",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.ip.address.wifi":"192.168.1.1",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.location":"Chicago Office",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.name":"examplePrefixToSkipOver",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.priority":"1",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.status.detail":"Placeholder-Text",
       "examplePrefixToSkipOver.dyn.prop.timestamp":"2010-01-01T12:00:00Z"

   }
 }
 ]
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: if your not looking at dom elements (sorry) you could compile a regular expression from the key value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for ( key in data[0].attributes ) {
    if (key.match('.dyn.prop.firmware')) {
       items.push(data[0].attributes[key]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cSF5w/

Comment: That would mean I have to put a lot of for loops in my code. Is there anyway I could have something global that just skips over the first part of the key so abc.my.data could be accessed by just sayin *.my.data

Comment: you could write a function. +1 to undefined

Comment: well lets say my json file has a thousand different attributes. Wouldn't I have to have a for loop for each one to specify [.dyn.prop.firmware, .dyn.prop.time, .dyn.prop.location etc]

Comment: @ndesign11 Well in that case you can remove the `firmware` from the string.

Comment: well some of them are abc.stat.prop.serial.number and xyz.stat.prop.serial.number the only difference being that first little part of the string. Wish there was an easy way to just let it accept anything for the first part of the string.

Comment: @ndesign11 Is using a `for` loop hard? You can create a function that accepts 2 parameters, one is the object and second one string to match.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand how I would accomplish that. I have hundreds of different types of formatting. I'll update my OP with more of the json to give a better picture.

Answer (score 2):

assumption of objects:

```
var my1 = [{
    "attributes": {
        "edgebox.act.halt": "1",
            "edgebox.dyn.prop.current.profile": "1",
            "edgebox.dyn.prop.firmware": "1.0"
    }
}];
var my2 = [{
    "attributes": {
        "qln220.act.halt": "1",
            "qln220.dyn.prop.current.profile": "1",
            "qln220.dyn.prop.firmware": "1.0"
    }
}];

var items = [];

function pdata(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items.push({mykey:val});
    });
}
pdata(my1[0].attributes);
pdata(my2[0].attributes);
alert(items[2].mykey);//alerts "1.0",
```

there are 6 objects in the array in this example

EDIT: Using those same objects but retaining the keys:

```
var items = [];

function pdata(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items.push({mykey:val,origkey:key});
    });
}
pdata(my1[0].attributes);
pdata(my2[0].attributes);
alert(items[2].mykey+ ":"+items[2].origkey);// alerts "1.0:edgebox.dyn.prop.firmware"
```

EDIT2: strip the first part:

```
function pdata(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items.push({
            mykey: val,
            origkey:(key.substring(key.indexOf(".")+1))
        });
    });
}
```

fiddle for your pleasure:http://jsfiddle.net/ThXHd/1/

Comment: I am just trying to look past the first part of the key string, I am not trying to do any matching after that first part because it could vary quite abit. I updated my json to show how much it varies. Though the variance is across all the different json files with the exception of the very first part of the key.

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing use of the key/value stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/ThXHd/ with your latest data

Comment: and this would work with my jquery from above? var items = [];
    $.each(data[0].attributes['*.dyn.prop.firmware'], function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });
    displaySortLabel(items, "type-details");

Comment: I added an updated example and fiddle which strips the first part.  You would simply pass the function your data attributes as I have doen with my1 and my2 as `pdata(data[0].attributes);`

Comment: I need something more generic. Could have a 1000 dif json files, and alert(items[2].mykey + ":" + items[2].origkey key 2 in one file might different in another file

Comment: So I basically need to access with a call to the key like this *.dyn.firmware.version with the asterisk being a catchall for anything that might be there

Comment: also the json is loaded via ajax, and could be one of thousands so setting up the m1 and m2 vars is impossible

Comment: Could I place this part of your code origkey:(key.substring(key.indexOf(".")+1)); into my original jquery from above?

Comment: Given your data, this is likely as generic as you are going to get.  Study the pure javascript functions in `key.substring(key.indexOf(".")+1)` - if you do not understand what that does you likely need to find a paid resource to do this for you ans that is really basic javascript stuff - not to insult you as we all had to start there, but get that understanding and you should be able to progress.

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = [];
for (key in data[0].attributes) {
    if (key.match('.stat.prop.type')) {
        items.push(data[0].attributes[key])
    }
}

displaySortLabel(items, "type-details");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't add comments to the earlier answer. You can make the function generic. Like so:

```
function getAttributesArray(obj, matchKey) {
   var items = [];
   for ( key in obj ) {
      if (key.match(matchKey)) {
          items.push(obj[key]);
      }
   }
   return items;
}

var label = getAttributesArray(data[0].attributes, '.dyn.prop.firmware')

displaySortLabel(label, "type-details");
```

Comment: Im not trying to match, I want to get rid of the first part of the string so "abc" in (abc.test.string.firmware)

Comment: Perhaps you should give an example of your input and what you want your output to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the first part of the key you can slice the key aftert the first index of '.' and use the modified values to map in to your model.

`var newKey = key.slice(key.indexOf('.') + 1)`

Comment: How would that work with the jQuery I created in my post? I can't seem to get your suggestion integrated without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Bonnarooster's example:

```
function getAttribute(attr, item) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(item.attributes, function (key, val) {
        if (key.slice(key.indexOf('.') + 1) == attr) 
            items.push(val);
    });
    return items;
};
```

Now you can call:

```
getAttribute('dyn.prop.current.profile', data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment on answers yet, but @undefined had exactly the right idea (although it should check it only matches the end of the attribute name). Here's how you'd put it in a function.

To get a single attribute:

```
function getOneWithSuffix(obj,suffix){
    for(var key in obj){
        if(key.substr(key.length-suffix.length)===suffix){
            return obj[key];
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
// usage: myValue = getOneWithSuffix( data[0].attributes, '.dyn.prop.current.profile' )
```

Or to get an array of all matching attribute values:

```
function getManyWithSuffix(obj,suffix){
    var ret=[];
    for(var key in obj){
        if(key.substr(key.length-suffix.length)===suffix){
            ret.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
// usage: myValuesArray = getManyWithSuffix( data[0].attributes, '.dyn.prop.current.profile' )
```

You could also use regular expressions in the matching if you want more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some of the other answers I think you want some "copy and paste" solution.

Here is wh'at i've got.

```
$.each(data[0].attributes, function(key, val){
     if(key.substr(key.indexOf('.',1)+1) === 'dyn.prop.current.profile')
         items.push(val);
});
```

I've just put what some people already answered in this fiddle, hope it works :D

http://jsfiddle.net/n3jca/1/